# Feature not activating, til 2nd attempt, no error

Tags: 2013, development, feature, feature-activation

I have a custom feature that, when activated, alters a document library (adds content types, sets up views, attaches a workflow).  For some reason, the first time I activate the feature nothing seems to happen.  The page refreshes but the feature still shows as deactivated.

When I look at the document library I can see some of the changes have been made, but not all.  When I activate the feature a second time the page correctly refreshes and shows the feature to be active - verified by looking at the document library which contains all changes.

There's nothing I can see in the ULS logs to tell me what happens the first time I try to activate, I've got no idea how I can debug this issue as attaching to the process and stepping through the code isn't an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please attach relevant part of your code to your post?

Comment: try in different browser? also when you activate it first time see if their is any browser error?

Answer (score 0):

If code is running too long the asp.net feature activation could be terminated.
Try to edit web.config in 14 hive

< location path="_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx" >
    < system.web >
      < httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" / >
    < /system.web>
  < /location >

I just set the time for one hour it's should be enough.